# Is it possible to query for a date property in objectbox?

Tags: android, objectbox

I'm trying to query my data for distinct dates. I've found property searches, but it doesn't look like they currently support searching for dates. Is there any way around this without having to store dates as a long or having to query the entire list and filtering it down? Even returning a list of entire objects where it grabs the first for each distinct date would be workable.

Comment: How do you store your dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open a feature request via GitHub issues. I'd suggest to query for long values, and create an array/list of dates using those.

Comment: They have add the feature in updated version. Please go through the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have filtered in **objectbox** using date:

```
public TOrder getTOrderByNumber(int number) {
    Long time = new Date().getTime();

    Date startDate = new Date(time - time % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    return tOrderBox.query().equal(TOrder_.orderNumber, number).between(TOrder_.date, startDate, endDate).build().findFirst();
}
```

It works for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use "ISO-8601 string" with OffsetDateTime

If you want to search for Object for today:

```
private val mFormatterDate = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE

@JvmStatic
    fun fromOffsetDate(date: OffsetDateTime?): String? {
        return date?.format(mFormatterDate)
    }


fun getWaterIntakes(): Pair<List<Water>, Float?> {
    val stringDate = TimeConverter.fromOffsetDate(OffsetDateTime.now())!!
    val list: List<Water> = mWaterBox.query().
        startsWith(Water_.date, stringDate)
        .order(Water_.date, QueryBuilder.CASE_SENSITIVE ).build().find()
    val firstMeasure: Float? = TimeConverter.convertISOToHours(list.firstOrNull()?.getTime())
    return Pair(list, firstMeasure)
}
```

Good bye!

Answer (score 0):

@Property(type: PropertyType.date) the best answer up to date is to mark your field as DateTime and set the property type to the @Property(type: PropertyType.date)

@override
Future<List> getByDateRange({
required DateTime start,
required DateTime end,
}) async {
return logsDb
.query(
LogModel_.date.between(
start.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
end.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
),
)
.build()
.find();
}

@override
Future<List> getByDate({
required DateTime date,
}) async {
return logsDb
.query(LogModel_.date.equals(date.millisecondsSinceEpoch))
.build()
.find();
}

here is an example